# Validation rule . sales lead(Custom Object) locked by another user only "sales Executive" tagging lookup(User) field should be editable all user

Tags: validation-rule

We can't save this record because the “Share Sales Lead Record” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION: You are not allowed to update this record. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 1229895365-40265 (-604557180)ok up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 1229895365-40265 (-604557180)

```
!ISCHANGED(Sales_Executive__c)&&
     Sales_Executive__r.Full_Name__c <>  Sales_Executive__c
```